# why none-www redirects to https

Tags: web, https, http-redirect

If I run "http://example.com" or "example.com" it redirects to https://www.example.com. Is there anyway I can stop this and ensure it just redirects to http://www.example.com. It doesn't seem to be anything controlled in the htaccess so I'm not sure where else to look. Here is the current htacess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
(and) RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/ [R=301,L]
```

were added to try and stop the problem but don't seem to do anything.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's your site doing the redirect and not your browser?

Comment: Yes it happens on all browsers however the result differs a little. On IE the url remains "http://" example.com but only because it says:  

The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address. Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server. We recommend that you close this webpage and do not continue to this website".... so it is also trying to direct to https :S